# profile = report(data) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, data-analysis

```
import profile
import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import profile_report as report
data = pd.read_csv(r"ifsc-code-of-syndicate-bank-_All-India_.csv")
print(data)

#generate a report
profile = report(data)

profile.to_file(output_file="ifsc.html")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the official documentation of this package, you should try this import instead:

```
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport as report
```

https://pandas-profiling.ydata.ai/docs/master/pages/getting_started/quickstart.html